# Как сделать такую штуку? и как она вообще называется?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовываются такое меню с навигацией, или как правильно это назвать?
как оно вообще называется?

Comment: Хлебные крошки.

Comment: А что именно непонятно в реализации? Обычные хлебные крошки, ничего нового вроде. Да, на SO принято показывать хоть небольшой кусок кода, который ты пытался сделать сам.

Comment: breadcrumbs, если не переводить на русский

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется хлебные крошки ([breadcrumb](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/))
Реализация в bootstrap

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Home</li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```